# How to upload document with metadata to SharePoint doc. library using Client Object Model?

Tags: sharepoint, object, model, client

I'm developing VSTO Outlook Add-In, so I'm using SharePoint Client Object Model. Can I upload a document to SharePoint doc. library and add metadata with one action? Using Google I have found many samples where metadata is added after uploading. Also I found out that it is possible to add metadata using full API(File.Add() method and a hashtable).

Help?

Answer (score 4):

You could use code like this:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("SITEURL");
Site site = context.Site;
Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(site);
context.Load(web);
context.ExecuteQuery();

List list = listCollection.GetByTitle("Reports");
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();

context.Load(list.RootFolder);
context.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Folder folder in list.RootFolder.Folders)
{
    if (folder.Name == "Folder-To-Upload")
    {
        FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();

        byte[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("SlmReportPeriods.xml"); // File which you want to upload

        fci.Content = array;
        fci.Overwrite = true;
        fci.Url = "Sample";
        File file = folder.Files.Add(fci);


        ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;
        item["Field1"] = "Example1";
        item["Field2"] = "ETC.";
        item.Update();

        folder.Files.Add(fci);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

The essence of this sample is to use FileCreationInformation and File objects and get ListItemAllFields of item.

Answer (score 0):

Redzio's answer worked for me.

Following code was derived from blog post [Upload Large Files to SharePoint Online](https://piyushksingh.com/2016/07/22/upload-large-files-to-sharepoint-online/) (by Piyush K Singh):

```
public File UploadLargeFileWithMetadata(ClientContext ctx, List docs, string fileName) {
    int blockSize = 8000000; // 8 MB
    string uniqueFileName = String.Empty;
    long fileSize;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = null;
    Guid uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();

    ctx.Load(docs.RootFolder, p = >p.ServerRelativeUrl);

    // Use large file upload approach
    ClientResult < long > bytesUploaded = null;

    FileStream fs = null;
    try {
        fs = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        fileSize = fs.Length;
        uniqueFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fs.Name);

        using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
            byte[] lastBuffer = null;
            long fileoffset = 0;
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead;
            bool first = true;
            bool last = false;

            // Read data from filesystem in blocks
            while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

                // We've reached the end of the file
                if (totalBytesRead <= fileSize) {
                    last = true;
                    // Copy to a new buffer that has the correct size
                    lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, lastBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                if (first) {
                    using(MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                        // Add an empty file.
                        FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                        fileInfo.ContentStream = contentStream;
                        fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
                        fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
                        uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

                        // Start upload by uploading the first slice.
                        using(MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {
                            // Call the start upload method on the first slice
                            bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
                            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                            // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added
                            fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                        }
                        ListItem Subs = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
                        Subs["Title"] = Convert.ToString(CompanyName.Value);
                        Subs["Address"] = Convert.ToString(Address.Value);
                        Subs["City"] = Convert.ToString(City.Value);
                        Subs["State"] = Convert.ToString(State.Value);
                        Subs["Zip"] = Convert.ToString(Zip.Value);
                        Subs["Country"] = Convert.ToString(Country.Value);
                        Subs["Website"] = Convert.ToString(WebSite.Value);
                        Subs.Update();
                        // we can only start the upload once
                        first = false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Get a reference to our file
                    uploadFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + uniqueFileName);

                    if (last) {
                        // Is this the last slice of data?
                        using(MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(lastBuffer)) {
                            // End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload
                            uploadFile = uploadFile.FinishUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                            // return the file object for the uploaded file
                            return uploadFile;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        using(MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {
                            // Continue sliced upload
                            bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                            // update fileoffset for the next slice
                            fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        this.Ex.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally {
        if (fs != null) {
            fs.Dispose();

        }
    }
    return uploadFile;
}
```

Comment: Good research, including the link. Please pay attention to proper code-formatting (e.g. using [C# online formatter](https://www.freecodeformat.com/c-format.php). If you can add own explanations it would make your answer even better :-)